# SQL Create Trigger Command Runs Fine Through MySQL Workbench But Errors When Called Through Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, triggers

I have the following code to create SQL setup a trigger (not yet a prepared statement).

```
commandList.Add($"DROP TRIGGER if exists `{tableName}_after_insert`;");
commandList.Add($"delimiter $$" + Environment.NewLine +
    $"CREATE TRIGGER `{tableName}_after_insert` AFTER INSERT" + Environment.NewLine +
    $"ON `{tableName}`" + Environment.NewLine +
    "FOR EACH ROW BEGIN" + Environment.NewLine +
    "Insert into HashEntry(TableName, TableRowId, TokenValue)" + Environment.NewLine +
    $"select '{tableName}', n.{tableKey}, 'tokenValue' from NEW n;" + Environment.NewLine +
    "END;" + Environment.NewLine +
    "$$" + Environment.NewLine +
    "delimiter ;");

//then some unrelated code until we execute

foreach (var command in commandList)
{
    Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);
}
```

This create the following SQL which works in Workbench and Entity Framework.

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists `MyTable_after_insert`;
```

And this which only works in Workbench directly.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `MyTable_after_insert` AFTER INSERT
ON `MyTable`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
Insert into HashEntry(TableName, TableRowId, TokenValue)
select 'MyTable', n.Id, 'tokenValue' from NEW n;
END;
$$
delimiter ;
```

Which gives the following error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `MyTable_after_insert` AFTER INSERT
```

I'm not sure why it would work directly in Workbench but not calling the same command through EF.

Any ideas?

Comment: At a guess maybe because you are using $$ possibly inside the string, what if you change it to something else?  its like it doesnt like the delimeter

Comment: I tried with three underscores ___ and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DELIMITER $$` is special syntax only understood by MySQL Workbench. It's not necessary when executing commands against a server using `MySqlCommand`. Just execute the SQL directly:

```
commandList.Add($@"CREATE TRIGGER `{tableName}_after_insert` AFTER INSERT
    ON `{tableName}`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    Insert into HashEntry(TableName, TableRowId, TokenValue)
    select '{tableName}', n.{tableKey}, 'tokenValue' from NEW n;
    END;");
```

(Note that I'm using [verbatim strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) to avoid all the concatenation with `Environment.NewLine`.)

Comment: That seems incredibly obvious now. It worked, thank you.